# Find $x$ such that $x \equiv7\pmod {37}$ and $x^2 \equiv 12\pmod {37^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $x$ such that $x \equiv7 \pmod {37}$ and $x^2 \equiv 12\pmod {37^2})$

My attempt: Given $x \equiv7\pmod {37}$

so $37|(x-7)$ so $37^2|(x-7)^2$

so $x^2-14x+49 \equiv 0\pmod {37^2}$

as $12-14x+49 \equiv 0\pmod{37^2}$ [as $x^2 \equiv 12\pmod {37^2}$]

so $14x\equiv 61\pmod {37^2}$  now I can find a set of solution using Euclidean algorithm

I would like some one to verify if this is correct as it seems longer and also is there a better and shorter method

Comment: So much time wasted on edits could have been used to answer some questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do $$(37n+7)^2=12\pmod{37^2}\\14n*37+49=12\pmod{37^2}\\14n+1=0\pmod{37}$$
which has a smaller modulo

Comment: makes perfect sense shame i didn't see it Thanks